# Python sniffer - the way to extract information from the package

Tags: python, sockets, networking, packet-capture

While examining a sniffer code written in Python, I saw that ethernet layer information was obtained from the first 14 characters of a packet and IP layer information from the first 20 characters of the same packet that includes ethernet layer informations. So how is both IP and Ethernet information obtained from the same part of a packet?

In short:

```
packet = s.recvfrom(65535)
ethernet_layer = packet[:14]
ip_layer = packet[:20] # includes ethernet layer
```

My opinion:

```
packet = s.recvfrom(65535)
ethernet_layer = packet[:14]
ip_layer = packet[14:34]
```

Sniffer code: https://github.com/shreyasgune/Packet-Sniffer/blob/master/sniff-it.py#L47

Comment: I think their implementation is bugged. When I wrote a basic packet sniffer using raw sockets, mine looked similar to your "opinion". The actual line I used was `relevant_data = packet_data[14:(14 + sizeof(constructor))]`, where `constructor` was a ctype class representing either an ARP or IP packet.

Comment: I think your observation is correct and that the code you refer too has a bug. But did you actually try out the code to make sure that it even works?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think so. The code also works, but I don't know how to check it for accuracy.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes I did. But how can I test its accuracy?

Comment: I don't think it "works" (although it may run without error). To verify it, start up a tool like Wireshark, listen on some simple traffic that you generate, then compare Wireshark's output to that of their program.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank you. I installed Wireshark and when I pinged my gateway address(192.168.1.1), the code I referenced didn't show the correct result.
As a result, my opinion is correct but the reference code is wrong.

Comment: If you want a super-simple base to work from, [here](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/dfb7e367f5d01e100305eb93955a7521) is an assignment that I had to do last semester. It's code adapted from the book Black Hat Python (or Grey Hat Python. We used both. I can't remember which exactly it's from). It's mostly all mine, except for the `IP` class.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank you. This will help me a lot.